# Regex Name Query Based on Phone Keypad

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

Just to start with at this point I have no example code, I'm asking for advise on whether this is possible and some pointers on how..

I've been asked to create a PHP script that will search our Windows LDAP Address Book.
To make things awkward I've been asked to do it so the front end looks like a phone keypad and the user enters names using the number pad.

As I see it the numbers will relate to letters as :

```
2 = ABC
3 = DEF
4 = GHI
5 = JKL
6 = MNO
7 = PQRS
8 = TUV
9 = WXYZ
```

I can see two different way to do this.

1. as the user enters there first digit start building an array of matches and then reducde this as they enter there second and third match.
2. build up a list of digits entered and then search for explicit matches.

Another issue I can see I will need to know which digit the user entered and when in the string.

eg: the user enters 6 4 5 This will need to match as :

```
M, N or O, as the first character.
G, H or I as the second character.
J, K or L as the thrid character.
```

Has anyone any advice, suggestions of pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: tell whichever manager specced that as an idea to stop being a retard? users have a full blown keyboard infront of them why the hell would they be entering letters off a phone style keypad. Besides you need javascript for handling inputs and letter filtering not regex in php. Use jquery and ajax for the actual pass letter to searches something like an autosuggest text box will work perfectly with your LDAP query page being the ajax requested page.

Comment: How many entries does that phone book have? An approximation would be enough

Comment: If you want it to work like a real oldschool digit phone then I suppose you need a short timer after the user has entered a character in case the user want to write the same character again. Eg. Aase. A - if the user presses 1 again within the timer then show B - if the user presses 1 again within the timer then show C etc and repeat, but if the timer has passed then write another A. Your task is pretty silly though!:)

Comment: thanks for the replies. I personally don't want a phone keypad, but that's not my call :( There around 3000 entries currently in the address book

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Dave that it really is a stupid idea, but before you're doing the whole filtering by hand, the LDAP filters might be a solution. You would have to create a huge filter for your possible combinations:

```
function getCombinations(array $digits = array())
{
    $digitToLetters = array(
        2 => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
        3 => array('D', 'E', 'F'),
        4 => array('G', 'H', 'I'),
        5 => array('J', 'K', 'L'),
        6 => array('M', 'N', 'O'),
        7 => array('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'),
        8 => array('T', 'U', 'U'),
        9 => array('W', 'B', 'Y', 'Z')
    );

    $values = array('');
    foreach ($digits as $digit) {
        $newValues = array();
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($digits[0], $digitToLetters)) {
                foreach ($digitToLetters[$digit] as $letters) {
                    $newValues[] = $value . $letters;
                }
            }
        }
        $values = $newValues;
    }

    return $values;
}

function getFilterForDigits(array $digits = array()) {
    $combinations = getCombinations($digits);
    $filter = '(|(sn=' . implode('*)(sn=', $combinations) . '*))';
}
```

It is assuming your filtering only by surname (`sn`), but you can easily change it, so it could fiter for `givenName` - remember that in case you want to filter for both, the filter size gets doubled which probably result in slower LDAP requests.

To filter for all possible results for the input `6`, `4`, `5` one would call:

```
$ds = ldap_connect("...");
$result = ldap_search($ds, "...", getFilterForDigits(array(6, 4, 5)));
```

I would still highly recommend against it, but if your hands are tied make sure you implement some sort of caching. :)

Comment: Thanks I will try this. 

I have made a start but in another direction. 

I've started to build an array of names based on an ldap search of the first digit entered. So if 2 is entered it returns to the array all names that starts A,B or C. This part is working.  

My plan was then to try to delete entries from the array based on the 2nd and 3rd digits entered. If if 3 is the 2nd digit entered remove anything from the array that doesn't have D,E or F as it's second character etc.. and then do the same for the 3rd digit.

Not sure if this is a good way or not !

Answer (score 0):

This of course limits the required calls to the LDAP. After you requested the names for your first digit you still can use the `getCombinations` function to filter for following digits:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) { 
    return !strncmp(strtoupper($haystack), $needle, strlen($needle)); 
} 


$combinations = getCombinations(array(6, 4, 5));
$results = array();
foreach ($resultsForFirstDigit as $ldapEntry) {
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        if (startsWith($ldapEntry['sn'], $combination) {
            $result[] = $ldapEntry;
        }
    }
}
```